# Remapping Capslock to Ctrl: Capslock-Shift-Tab does not work as Ctrl-Shift-Tab

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I remapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> using gnome-tweak-tool.

When I try to switch tabs *forwards* in Chromium or Firefox with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it works fine.

However, when I try <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tabs *backwards*, it doesn't work.

Using [screenkey](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey) I can see that the input that is shown when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (**no <kbd>Tab</kbd> input registered, and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**)

Seems like <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> registers as a different command altogether.

How can I make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behave the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in this situation?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: just tried, works fine for my with firefox and chrome